# multi-driven net, or reg not being driven

Tags: verilog

I'm working on an assignment where I need to create a jackpot game. But I'm having trouble driving the register that controls the win condition and I can't figure out why. As far as I know, the always@(posedge zero) block should be able to run whenever I flip my switch to the up position. Then, so long as the right hot register value happens in the same instant, it should be able to set the win register. However, this is not the case. Nothing seems to happen, and I'm not sure why. I've tried running the always block from different sensitivities but nothing seems to effect it. Maybe I'm just mis-understanding how always blocks work or how the switch works, any help is appreciated.

```css
module jackpot(
    input [3:0] SWITCHES,
    output [3:0] LEDS,
    input CLOCK,
    input reset
    );
    
    reg [3:0] hot = 4'd1;
    reg win;
    wire clk, zero, one, two, three;
    Clock_Div CDD (CLOCK, clk);
    
    assign LEDS[2:0] = hot[2:0];
    assign zero = SWITCHES[0];
    assign one = SWITCHES[1];
    assign two = SWITCHES[2];
    assign three = SWITCHES[3];
    assign LEDS[3] = zero;
    
    initial begin
        win <= 1'b0;
    end
    
    always @(posedge zero) begin
        if(hot[0] && zero)
            win <= 1'd1;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (reset == 1'b1) begin
            hot <= 4'd1;
            win <= 1'd0;
        end
        else if(win == 1'b1) begin
            hot <= 4'b1111;
        end
        else begin
            if(hot == 4'b1000) begin
                hot <= 4'b0001;
            end
            else begin
                hot <= hot << 1;
            end
        end
    end
    
    
endmodule
```

Comment: Are you intending to make hardware out of this? If so, you have bigger problems. This code is not synthesisable. You need to sort that out before worrying about the details of its behaviour. Basically, you need to find out about synthesisable coding styles in Verilog and you need to work out what hardware you are trying to create before you start coding.

Comment: you should not drive 'win' from different always blocks. it makes simulation behavior unpredictable.

Comment: @Serge thanks for the comment, that was exactly the problem. Must have been glossed over in class or something. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Serge's comment I've realized the issue. Like his comment says, driving a register from multiple always blocks throws a critical warning, and Vivado picks one of the blocks to use over the other. Once I made sure to isolate a reg to an always block the behavior started to look like I expected. This must just be something that got glossed over during class, or maybe I wasn't paying attention enough.